# Modifying an object in Boost shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

I'm learning shared memory of boost to apply it to my OpenCV project.
These are two snippets for testing.

class.h

```
#ifndef _class_H_
#define _class_H_
class Myclass{
public:
    Myclass() : number(0){}
    int number;
};
#endif
```

write.cpp

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "include/class.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   using namespace boost::interprocess;
   struct shm_remove{
      shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
   } remover;
   managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
   Myclass *instance = segment.construct<Myclass>("instance1")();          
   instance = new Myclass();
   std::system("read.exe");
   std::cout << instance->number << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

read.cpp

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "include/class.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
    std::pair<Myclass*, managed_shared_memory::size_type> res;
    res = segment.find<Myclass> ("instance1");
    res.first->number = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

Surely the output must be 3, but it is 0, which means that the class is not modified.
How can I modify an object in shared memory?

Comment: You are not using the instance created in the shared memory, instead you are creating a local one and outputting its value (`instance = new Myclass();`).

Comment: There's not a single line of OpenCV code here. Please, don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: @DanMašek My mistake. I forgot to remove it

Comment: @eukaryota I made a silly mistake. Thanks!